# Python: Want to write zipfile.ZipFile object to disk as "foo.zip"

Tags: python, io, zip

It feels like I'm missing something obvious here.

I have a zipfile.ZipFile object, which was created by writing files into it using io.BytesIO() called `buffer` as follows:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, "a") as zip:
    # write some things into the zip using zip.write()
```

then I returned `zip`, so I have a zipfile.ZipFile object.

I want to write this object to disk as a zipped file, and I don't know how.

```
zip.write('foo.zip')
```

would write things *into* the object, and

```
with open('foo.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(zip)
```

doesn't work because `zip` isn't a bytes object.

```
with open('foo.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(zip.read())
```

doesn't work because it's expecting a "name", which I presume is the name of one of the files saved within zip.
I would have assumed there was just some simple way to do this, e.g. `zip.to_zip("foo.zip")`?

UPDATE:
Because `zip` was originally written into the buffer, I tried changing zip.filename to `"test.zip"` which does write the zip to disk. However, the contents of `zip` aren't there. This could be a different issue, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write contents of `buffer`, not `zip`, since everything you write using `zip.write(filename)` is being put into the buffer, as you passed it as a first argument of `zipfile.ZipFile()` call.

I would also suggest to avoid using `zip` as a variable name since it shadows built-in `zip(*iterables)` function.

Here is an example:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, "a") as zip_file:
    zip_file.write('data.txt')

with open('foo.zip', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(buffer.getvalue())
```